# Practice with another $e^{At}$

Tags: matrices, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, jordan-normal-form

Given the matrix: $A=\begin{pmatrix}-2&0&0\\4&-2&0\\1&0&-2\end{pmatrix}$, find $e^{At}$.

I found the eigenvalues to be $-2,-2,-2$.
I need to use the Jordan form to solve it. I'm practicing for exam in a couple of hrs.
Thank you.
I found the eigenvectors, $$v_1=(0,1,0), v_2=(0,1,1), V_3=(1,0,0).$$

I think the Jordan form is $e^{Jt}=\begin{pmatrix}e^{-2t}&1&0\\0&e^{-2t}&1\\0&0&e^{-2t}\end{pmatrix}$,Is this right?

Next I need to calculate $$Ve^{Jt}V^{-1}$$ Actually I do know the answer Im just  practicing the way to do it. Can anybody tell me whats wrong with V_3? I found that $(A+2I)^3=0$ and I thought any eigenvector satisfies $0\cdot v_3=0$?!

Comment: You'll need the eigenvectors for the next step.

Comment: @ hans what is the form of E^Jt?

Comment: $V_3$ is not an eigenvector.

Comment: @Hans how do you find the second generalized eigenvector? how can you tell that it is not?

Comment: Here is another hint; see the worked example under calculations (assuming you understand Hans' comment about the need for the eigenvectors): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential

Comment: @ amzoti how do you find the second generalized eigenvector?

Comment: See the examples here (do you understand algebraic and geometric multiplicity): http://www.math.vt.edu/people/afkhamis/class_home/notes/F08W12.pdf

Comment: @Klara - use the eigenvectors $e_2 = (0,1,0)^T$ and $e_3 = (0,0,1)^T$ for the single eigenvalue $\lambda = -2$. The missing generalized eigenvector $x$ has the property that $(A - \lambda I) x = \alpha e_2 + \beta e_3$. When you write out what this means, you'll  see that $x = (1,0,0)^T$ works.  Good luck with your exam.

Answer (score 3):

The form of $e^{At}$ can be guessed by computing a few powers of $A$ by hand. One sees that these powers are all of the form 
$$
\begin{pmatrix} a &0 & 0 \\ b & a & 0 \\ c & 0 & a
\end{pmatrix}   
$$
where $a$ is a power of (-2). Therefore one can guess that
$$
e^{At} = \begin{pmatrix} e^{-2t} &0 & 0 \\ f(t) & e^{-2t} & 0 \\ g(t) & 0 & e^{-2t}
\end{pmatrix}   
$$
with some functions $f(t), \, g(t)$ that need to be determined. Since $e^{0 \cdot A}$ is the identity matrix, we know that $f(0) = g(0) = 0$.

Using the differential equation $\frac{d}{dt} e^{At} = A e^{At}$ one obtains differential equations for $f$ and $g$ which can be easily solved.

Comment: even easier:  $M = -2I + N$ and $N^2 = 0$